# stucking data sending throw ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a footer.php file and i already wrote the code in ajax which is blow here when i alert data variable then i got id but in success function i didn't get anything .olease somebody help me
    
    © Copyright 2013-2015 Khan's 
    Boutique

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
var vscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
jQuery('#logotext').css({
    "transform" : "translate(0px, "+vscroll/2+"px)"
});

jQuery('#back-flower').css({
    "transform" : "translate("+0+vscroll/5+"px, -"+vscroll/12+"px)"
});

jQuery('#fore-flower').css({
    "transform" : "translate(0px, -"+vscroll/2+"px)"
});
});

function detailsmodal(id){
var data = 'id='+ id;
//alert(data);
jQuery.ajax({
url: '/boutique/includes/detailsmodal.php',
method:"post",
data : data,
success: function(data){
//alert(data);
jQuery('body').append(data);
jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
},
error: function(){
alert("something went wrong!");
}
});
};  
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: can you post request/response data? Also avoid using same variable names for 2 different scope like request `data` and response `data`

Answer (score 0):

Your `var data` should be like this :

```
var data = {
    id: id
}
```

And in success, the data is the returned to the ajax where the ajax request is sent.

Comment: i have alredy send u footer .php then what u need

Comment: y m not getting id in detailsmodal.php can u tell  me

Comment: my first alert working fine here i got id after that code some problem

Comment: Replace the data : data in your ajax with data : {id : id}, then check the id at your detailsmodal.php file

Comment: Could you provide your updated code what you tried ?

Comment: can u send me your skype id

Comment: give me your email id so that i will send u olease help me out this problem